# How to find appropriate syntax for 1 or more integers followed by a non-integer with OR conditions in between?

Tags: regex, jenkins, jenkins-plugins

I would like to find regex to match the following base case and its deviations:

```
0 errors | 0 warnings | 0 notes
```

Deviations could be just any positive integer `>= 0` on errors, warnings and notes:

```
0 errors | 1 warnings | 0 notes
0 errors | 0 warnings | 1 notes
1 errors | 0 warnings | 0 notes
1 errors | 1 warnings | 1 notes
8 errors | 2 warnings | 12 notes
8 errors | 2 warnings | 12 notes
```

and so on.

Im not sure how to find the appropriate regex for 1 or more integers followed by a non-integer with `OR`conditions in between:

```
^[0-9]+[^0-9]\(errors|warnings|notes)$
```

Im actually trying Jenkins to exit if error, warning and note are occurring in devtools::check(), which tests some R package. Since Jenkins build is marked as success regardless of notifications and errors. Therefore I would like to use  Text-Finder plugin plugin, which uses regex to mark build as success and failure.

Comment: Sounds like `^\d+\s+(?:errors|warnings|notes)$`

Comment: You should have received an error when trying your regex. Did you? What are the results you are trying to get? Also, see [`[0-9]+ *(errors|warnings|notes)`](https://regex101.com/r/xxwR1W/1) demo.

Comment: Hi @WiktorStribiżew, yes I get `Error: '\(' is an unrecognized escape in character string starting ""[0-9]+[^0-9]\("`

Comment: Hi @WiktorStribiżew, Im actually trying Jenkins to exit if error, warning and note are occurring in devtools::check(), which tests some R package. Since jenkins build is marked as success regardless of that notifications and errors. I have the TextFind plugin, which uses regex to mark build as success and failure.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew, not sure what you mean with code. There is no code, just an output, which I have explained above. Only regex is needed. Not sure why other tags are required here.

Comment: Ok, just studied the source code a bit, and it seems to use Java regex. Now, what are you trying to match? A whole line with digits + "errors", space, `|`, space, digits + "warnings", space, `|`, space, digits + "notes"? Try [`^[0-9]+ *errors [|] [0-9]+ *warnings [|] [0-9]+ *notes$`](https://regex101.com/r/xxwR1W/2)

Comment: yes, exactly: digits + "errors", space, |, space, digits + "warnings", space, |, space, digits + "notes" !

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew, pretty amazing thx!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, you need a pattern that matches the exact pattern as above. Use:

```
^[0-9]+ *errors [|] [0-9]+ *warnings [|] [0-9]+ *notes$
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/xxwR1W/2/)

**Details**

- `^` - start of string
- `[0-9]+` - 1 or more digits
- `*` - zero or more space (change `*` to `+` to match 1 or more)
- `errors` - a literal substring
- `[|]`  - a `|` char enclosed with spaces
- `[0-9]+` - 1 or more digits
- `*` - zero or more space (change `*` to `+` to match 1 or more)
- `warnings` - a `warnings` substring
- `[|]`  - a `|` char enclosed with spaces
- `[0-9]+` - 1 or more digits
- `*` - zero or more space (change `*` to `+` to match 1 or more)
- `notes` - a substring
- `$` - end of string.